# My image is again and again going to the top left corner of the screen and nothing is fixing it

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout

This the code of my image
Which I inputted in the image after much research

```
<Image
    app:constraintToLeft_ToLeftOf="parent"
    app:constraintToRight_ToRightOf="parent"
    app:constraintToBottom_ToBottomOf="parent"
    app:constraintToTop_ToTopOf="parent"
/>
```

Also my image shows no tag defined which is very frustrating whenever I add an object to the screen either in design view or text view the result is always the same. Nothing is helping me in resolving the issue.
I also tried different solution give to others but it is always at the same position even if I drag it to the center of the view

Comment: And I have the latest version of Android studio with all updated. And I have all sdk's installed and my project was successfully builded and the grade sync finished without any interruption still not working

Comment: Android xml has no <Image> tag, Please  use <ImageView> instead of <Image>.

Comment: Even after writing image view it is showin` a error and it is again aligning to top left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android xml has no `<Image>` tag, Please use `<ImageView`> instead of `<Image>`

There are not such attributes like `constraintToLeft_ToLeftOf`,      `constraintToRight_ToRightOf`,  `constraintToBottom_ToBottomOf`,  `constraintToTop_ToTopOf` in `ConstraintLayout`

Check this documentation for more details - [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout)

Try this code:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: Thanks now it is working but my code was ore-generated but your code worked